# Batch problems with variable forwarding

Tags: variables, batch-file, forward-declaration

i have a problem with my batch. If a variable is not available, I should be forwarded to another (to give an error message). Here I have a section of the file:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo.
echo [1] ---
echo [2] ---
echo [3] ---
echo [4] ---
echo [5] ---
echo [6] ---
echo [M] ---
echo.
echo.
set /p SD1=Enter: 
if "%sd1%"=="1" goto shutdown
if "%sd1%"=="2" goto shutdownr
if "%sd1%"=="3" goto sleep
if "%sd1%"=="4" goto cold
if "%sd1%"=="5" goto left
if "%sd1%"=="6" goto remotesd
if "%sd1%"=="M" goto SysM
if "%sd1%"=="m" goto SysM
echo.
goto sd

:shutdown
pause
exit

:error
cls
color CF
echo.
echo Error 0x%random% 
pause
```

Now, if i enter "1" and the "shutdownn" variable is not available, i would like go to "error". How can I do it? I am grateful for every little help I get. Thank you for your attention.

Comment: What do you mean "not available?" Variables are always available. Do you mean if the variable isn't defined?

Comment: Do you mean  `:shutdownn` [label](http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html) by _"shutdownn" variable_? Try `if "%sd1%"=="1" goto :shutdown||goto :error`. [Source](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Comment: @SomethingDark I mean that, when i did a mistake with setting variables should i forwarded to another variables (like an error message)

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for anwser but it doesent work, I have the same problem that the jump destination cannot found.